# using JDBC Connection Pool with SQL Azure Database gives "Error in allocating a connection"

Tags: database, windows, jdbc, azure, glassfish

I have a Java EE web application deployed on glassfish 3.1.1 which I want to host on Windows Azure.

The application uses hibernate as jpa.

I defined a JDBC Connection Pool for the Azure database.

(basically, these are the defaults)

Initial and Minimum Pool Size: 8 Connections

Maximum Pool Size: 32 Connections

Pool Resize Quantity: 2 Connections

Idle Timeout: 300 Secconds

Max Wait Time: 60000 Milliseconds

Additional Properties:

User: user@serverName

ServerName: serverName.database.windows.net

Password: myPass

databaseName: mydatabase

If i ping it from the glassfish interface it works, so the properties I provide are ok.

Setting the new jdbc connection pool (the one for azure) resulted in the tables being created on the sql azure database (i have "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" set to update) - so there isn't a problem with the database connection/parameters.

If the application uses the database immediately after the server started, all goes well (it can retrieve/store data)

When the application tries to use the database after being idle for a while, I get this:

[link to exception](http://pastebin.com/xZmE1er2)

If I flush the connection (from glassfish admin) it starts to work again, until it goes idle for a period of time.

So basically, as long as it executes database operations all works well, but if there are no database operations for a while, the next db operation will result in that exception.

I've google'd this and it seems to have something to do with the azure database server closing the idle connection, but I couldn't find a solution for the problem.

I never had this problem when using PostgreSql

Answer (score 1):

One possible reason cause this problem: SQL Azure closes idle connections after 5 minutes. To work around this issue, you have to close the connection, and create a new connection. In general, it is recommended to close idle connections even when connecting to other databases. This helps to reduce system resource usage.